# Google BigQuery: Delete Statement for several tables in one query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dml

It is possible to delete rows in several tables in one query?

Like this :

```
delete FROM project.dataset.table1, project.dataset.table2, project.dataset.table3
where id not in 
(
    select distinct id from project.dataset.table4
)
```

Is there a way to do this ??

Comment: Do the tables have a `foreign key constraints` between them?

Comment: Tables with different FK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DML is usually on one table.  It is possible to perform many operations on the single table using a MERGE Statement.

All three deletes will need to be performed indivudually.

bq utility enables multiple query statements to be processed if they are passed as a single sql file.

**mydeletefile.sql**

```
delete FROM dataset.table1 where id not in 
(select distinct id from dataset.table4);

delete FROM dataset.table2 where id not in 
(select distinct id from dataset.table4);

delete FROM dataset.table3 where id not in 
(select distinct id from dataset.table4);
```

Run bq

```
cat mydeletefile.sql | bq query --use_legacy_sql=false
```

(assumes `bq init` has been run already and project is configured)

As @T0ny1234 comments need to check FK constraints are not in breach.
But bottom line - multiple table row delete is not a concept normally even considered and not seen in any SQL implementations *happy to be corrected*

Comment: Thanks for the answer !! I can run this as one scheduled query?

Comment: If you are using cron or airflow - there should be no reason not to have this batch as a single schedule.  - and if in windows the same  - just change the command  to type mydeletefile.sql | bq query --use_legacy_sql=false  (instead of cat)